# query to write multiple matched strings in single query by using RegExp

Tags: sql, plsql, sql-like, regexp-like

I wanted to write a query to not match with the mentioned strings
Requirement as below

```sql
SELECT *
FROM fnd_lookups_all
WHERE lookup_type = 'SELECTION_TAX'
      AND source_value = p_input_source
      AND attribute1 = tax_aut_num
      AND attribute2 = -p_remi_code
      AND attribute6 = TO_CHAR ('RBC')
      AND lookup_code NOT LIKE '%POF%' OR NOT LIKE '%AT%';
```

How should I improve this query?

Comment: What needs to be improved?  If it is valid and runs, then what is the problem here?

Comment: If you planned to rewrite it so that it uses regular expressions, note that such a solution might actually run *slower* than your current code.

Comment: I wanted to write these two conditions into a single condition, is there any chance to write that by using regular expression 
conditions : AND lookup_code NOT LIKE '%POF%' OR NOT LIKE '%AT%';

Comment: I believe the best way to improve this query is by using indexes, rather than changing the code: https://www.orafaq.com/node/1918 but you could `and not regexp_like(lookup_code, 'POF|AT')` if you really wanted